# Multiplicative Persistence program in android

Tags: java, android

Hello i have this problem taken from codewars.

"Write a function, persistence, that takes in a positive parameter num and returns its multiplicative persistence, which is the number of times you must multiply the digits in num until you reach a single digit."

im having some trouble in applying the method.This is what i have so far.

```
 public static int digital_root(int n) {
    // ...

    char[] characters = Integer.toString(n).toCharArray();
    int sum = 0;
    String number=Integer.toString(n);
    int lengNum=number.length();
    String firstChar=number.substring(0,1);
    String secondChar=number.substring(1,2);

    for(int i=0;i<=lengNum;i++){
        int a;
        number.substring(i,i+1);
        number.substring(i+1,i+2);
    }

    for (char character : characters) {
        int x = Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(character));
        sum += x;
    }
    if (sum > 10) {
        return digital_root(sum);
    } else {
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Since i dont know the lenght of n it could be 100000000

i know that here is the key to this

```
for(int i=0;i<=lengNum;i++){
    int a;
    number.substring(i,i+1);
    number.substring(i+1,i+2);
}
```

but here comes my big question i could store the value of `number.substring(i,i+1);`
 into a variable say `Int a = number.substring(i,i+1);`

and then do the same thing with variable `Int b=number.substring(i+1,i+2);`

and then return a*b but how to do `a*b*c*d*........`

Then i would have to do in the for loop

```
if(number<10){
 return number;
}else{
   //continue multiplying
}
```

im having the following error:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.franco.mac.any/com.franco.mac.any.MainActivity}: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=3
```

Comment: That for loop is not doing anything except spinning and throwing exceptions. Why is it there?. Also, it's looks like your adding instead of multiplying. And why do this on Android?

Comment: Hello James. i understand that the for loop needs adjustments that is because i ask the questions, the other code is because i was doing the same exercise but with additions , but if is replace the += with *= it didnt work.And i do it on Android Studio to log and debugg the app and see whats wrong with the program.

Comment: The for loop with the substring calculations doesn't have any function, is completely superfluous, and should be deleted in it's entirety. It would be a NO-OP if it didn't throw an exception. The subsequent for loop solves the problem.

Comment: Yes james but if i change the += for *= it doesnt do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you just want something like this? If you want it to work with very large numbers you could use BigInteger.

```
public static int persistence(int num) {
    int numberOfTimes = 0;
    int temp;
    while (num > 9) {
        temp = 1;
        while (num > 0) {
            temp *= num % 10;
            num /= 10;
        }
        num = temp;
        numberOfTimes++;
    }
    return numberOfTimes;
}
```